# Create custom font families with Fontconfig

Tags: fontconfig

I'm starting to dive into using [sway](https://swaywm.org/) + [waybar](https://github.com/Alexays/Waybar). For styling my Waybar, my ultimate goal is to be able to have it use monochrome emoji and prevent color emoji from appearing. However, I want to have color emoji everywhere else on my system, so disabling color emojis system-wide is non-ideal. Any way I can achieve this goal is fine, maybe it's not necessarily a Fontconfig solution.

My current thought process was to create a "custom font family" in Fontconfig specifically for Waybar to use, and then make sure this custom font family doesn't try to use color emojis. If successful, I could see myself using this pattern in a few other places across my system as well.

So, in my `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`, I have the following match element:

```
<match>
  <test name="family"><string>Waybar Font</string></test>
  <edit name="family" mode="delete_all"></edit>
  <edit name="family" mode="prepend_first" binding="strong">
    <string>Noto Sans</string>
    <string>Noto Sans Symbols</string>
    <string>Noto Sans Symbols 2</string>
  </edit>
</match>
```

When I `fc-cache -fv && fc-match "Waybar Font" -s | head -n 10`, I get:

```
NotoSans-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans" "Regular"
NotoSans-Italic.ttf: "Noto Sans" "Italic"
NotoSansSymbols-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Symbols" "Regular"
NotoSansSymbols2-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Symbols 2" "Regular"
NotoNastaliqUrdu-Regular.ttf: "Noto Nastaliq Urdu" "Regular"
NotoSansWarangCiti-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Warang Citi" "Regular"
NotoSansAdlam-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Adlam" "Regular"
NotoSansDuployan-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Duployan" "Regular"
NotoSansSyriacEastern-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Syriac Eastern" "Regular"
NotoSansMath-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Math" "Regular"
```

(there are 177 lines of output, which I'm surprised by since I tried to `delete_all`, but I figure adding `Noto Sans` probably adds a bunch of fonts...?)

Waybar's stylesheet uses this `Waybar Font`:

```
* {
    font-family: "Waybar Font";
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

(no other `font-family` directives anywhere else)

However, when I reload Waybar, it seems to still use the `Noto Color Emoji` version for :

[image: color emoji used]

AFAICT, the first font that contains this glyph (given the above output) is `NotoSansSymbols2-Regular.ttf`, and it should look like this (see [Glyphs](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Symbols+2/glyphs)):

[image]

Am I misunderstanding how Fontconfig works? Is it possible to do what I'm attempting to do?

Answer (score 0):

Upon searching more, it seems like [this blog post](https://mefody.dev/chunks/emoji-to-text/) has some relevant information. Copying relevant info here:

- , by itself, is a generic "speaker with three sound waves". It might be rendered either with color emoji or with text, depending on your system setup.
- ️ is the first character plus an additional `U+FE0F` codepoint appended to it. `U+FE0F` is a "variation selector", in this case specifying to render the color emoji variant.
- ︎ is the first character plus an additional `U+FE0E` codepoint appended to it. `U+FE0E` is another variation selector, this time specifying to render the text variant.

(copy-paste each of these into https://unicode-explorer.com/search/, you'll see that they're using different unicode encodings)

In the Waybar configs, you can append `&#xFE0F;` or `&#xFE0E;` (respectively) to your emoji to force one rendering or another, assuming you have the "base" codepoint before it. Eg. `&#xFE0E;` will render `︎`. Alternatively, you can just copy-paste the complete "forced" version into your configs now that you know there's a difference. :)

I'm still interested if there's a way to "force text-based emojis for custom fonts" in Fontconfig, though.